# Why is the cell height is zero

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I want to place a object at the center of my custom cell. Therefore I need to get the center of my custom cell in it's initialization.

So I tried this line of code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let center = self.contentView.center
}
```

But from some reason the center point retuned was - (0,0)

Then I checked the height of the cell:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    println(self.contentView.bounds.height)
}
```

And it returned that the height is 0

Why does it happen? Should I initialize my cell and it's contents somewhere else?

Comment: Could you try to put the view in center of your cell using AutoLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which was to override layoutSubviews() function. This function is called after the cell height is setup.

Answer (score 0):

The cell is not laid out as soon as it is loaded. Try putting the same code in `viewWillAppear` or maybe `viewDidAppear`.